# Como cambiar el prototipo según la función?

Tags: javascript

***Según este código:***

```
function Oa() {

this.edad = "";
this.nombre = "";

}

Oa.prototype = {

w: true

};
```

Todo bien hasta aquí, pero como podría ***aplicar el prototipo a todos PERO excepto a una método determinado***, por ejemplo si tengo:

```
  Oa.prototype.ges = function() {

    console.log(this.w ? 1 : 2);

    };

var nw = new Oa();

nw.ges();
```

Pero necesito que si o si, se aplique a todos, **excepto** a el método `ges`, que debo hacer?

Comment: Para que exactamente? Porque sencillamente no la quitas del `prototype` si no la quieres?

Comment: La única razón que veo para esto es simular un método privado que no será heredado. No le veo mucho sentido a la pregunta; ¿Podrías explicar qué quiered lograr con esto?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía eso necesito exacto

Answer (score 0):

deberias sacar el prototype para no utilzarla

```
  Oa.ges = function() {
      console.log(this.w ? 1 : 2);
  };

  var nw = new Oa();
```

Saludos